# On topic for the website

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions about a research paper I am writing and for introducing a thesis, and antithesis techniques? Like I am writing a paper 15 pages long and I wanted to know how to create a formulaic approach for each paragraph the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're not writing a "what to write" question, which is outside the scope of this site, and keep it to asking about techniques and general advice instead, that should be fine. For example, you specifically asked about creating a formulaic approach for each paragraph of the paper, which would be on-topic under the [organization](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organization) tag.

You should also be careful not to get too broad - i.e. "What are some common thesis techniques for an academic paper?" might have too many potential answers and be closed as a broad question or a duplicate.